# Footer Doesn't Stay Where It Should Be

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to make a footer at the bottom of my site and I actually did but doesn't stay where I want it to be. The original CSS code that I use is this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
width: 1270px;
position: absolute;
color: white;
bottom: 0px;
display: block;
font-size: smaller;
text-align: center;
```

But my page's height grows everytime someone send a comment. So I know what the problem is here. When I add bottom: 0px, it always stays at 0px, but when page's height grows, footer stays there. When I change position: fixed, that works but then the footer goes over comments when I scroll up/down but I want it to stay always at the bottom. When I delete positioning, it does the trick, it stays at the bottem of the page always but then it causes to apply background-color, border, border-radius etc. to all the page, I don't want that to happen. I want codes apply only to the footer.

I would like to hear some advices. Thank you already!

Edit! Here is the rest of the CSS that effects the footer;

```css
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 39px;
}
darkly.min.css:14
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10.5px;
}
darkly.min.css:14
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: inherit;
}
darkly.min.css:14
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}
darkly.min.css:14
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from body
darkly.min.css:14
body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: white;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/491274240789482793/1CEE148DBE320A9367BCDF5211AE077E695A4CFE/);
    text-transform: lowercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
}
Inherited from html
darkly.min.css:14
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
darkly.min.css:14
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
darkly.min.css:14
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
darkly.min.css:14
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: You should include the HTML and the rest of the CSS that is related to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `position: relative` for the `html` element, which will set [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) appropriately, allowing your code to work. You should also set `min-height: 100%` for it, while you are at it. I have created a simple tester below, which randoly changes the height of the content when you click the button. Try it out and let me know how you feel about it!

```js
var height = 100;

function updateHeight() {
  if (height >= 100)
    height = (50 * Math.random());
  else
    height = (75 + 50 * Math.random());
  document.getElementById("variable-height").setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + height + 'vh');
}
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1270px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="variable-height" style="height: 100vh;">
  <button onclick='updateHeight()'>Click me to test!</button></div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: That definetely did the trick, works like charm. And I gotta admit that your solution is quite clever. Thank you!